# Как можно получить продолжительность видео?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

У меня есть видео, которое мне нужно обрезать с помощью FFmpeg. Для этого мне нужно получить его полную длительность. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Вам точно нужен для этого питон? `mediainfo video.avi |grep Duration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продолжительность видео хранится в метаданных файла. 
Используйте утилиту ffprobe (часть пакета ffmpeg). 
Примерно так будет выглядеть команда:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 some_file.mp4
```